# Weird bug with exiftool and Hazel photo workflow

Tags: finder, photos, bug, macos

I have a weird bug I'm experiencing. I have a folder of images that Hazel doesn't recognize as images. These are located in a folder that I have set to be monitored by Hazel using a script made with `exiftool` that will organize the photos into folders by year/month/day. The `exiftool` script follows and works for "normal" images.

```
exiftool "-Directory<DateTimeOriginal" -d %Y/%m/%d%%-c "/Volumes/VolumeName/Photos"
```

Oddly enough, `exiftool` doesn't recognize these photos as well, even if I run the script from the command line. What's even more frustrating is that the workflow will work for some photos and not for others.

Some observations:

- Finder recognizes these trouble files as photos when I do a Spotlight search using the terms `kind:image`.
- Hazel does **not** treat the trouble files as images. I know this because I can set a rule to move all files but images to a different folder and those troublesome files will be moved.
- It doesn't appear to be a permissions issue
- It doesn't seem to have anything to do with the format of the photo (jpg, jpeg, JPG, png, NEF)

**In short, both Hazel and the `exiftool` script work but not for certain photos I have (and thousands of them at that!)**

1. Do you have any idea what's going on and why these photos aren't being properly recognized as such?
2. How do Hazel and `exiftool` differ from Finder in their determination of whether or not a file is an image?

Comment: What does `file troubled-file.png` return? Does it differ from the result of `file untroubled-file.png`?

Comment: The working file will give: `2014-04-19 at 16-35-38.jpeg: JPEG image data, EXIF standard 2.21`

Some, but not all, trouble files will give: `2014-09-02 at 13-26-06.jpg: JPEG image data`. The other trouble files will give something similar to the working files, as above.